# pandas normalize simple JSON

Tags: json, pandas, normalize

I have a simple JSON data like:

```
[{
    "load": 1,
    "results": {
        "key": "A",
        "timing": 1.1
    }
}, {
    "load": 2,
    "results": {
        "key": "B",
        "timing": 2.2
    }
}]
```

When trying to load it to pandas:

```
pd.read_json('res.json')
```

The result looks like:
[image]

But Instead of having `key`, `value` as separate columns they are still nested.
How can these be normalized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`json.json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
data = [{
    "load": 1,
    "results": {
        "key": "A",
        "timing": 1.1
    }
}, {
    "load": 2,
    "results": {
        "key": "B",
        "timing": 2.2
    }
}]

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(data)
print (df)
   load results.key  results.timing
0     1           A             1.1
1     2           B             2.2
```

If need data from file:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json

with open('sample.json') as f:    
    data = json.load(f)  

df = json_normalize(data)
```

Comment: But I have to load the JSON manually from file to string? Or is there some integrated method?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler - Answer was edited.